# GoDaddy cPanel SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE Permissions After Logout

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am attempting to recover statements within procedures in a MySQL database. It seems that when using cPanel through GoDaddy, the user changes when logging in through PHPMyAdmin, resulting in the 'definer' of a procedure being different than the current user after a single logout. This seems to prevent SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE from returning a proper CREATE statement due to permissions.

A workaround is perhaps defining a user and using the account in defining procedures. While not desirable, it may be sufficient.

Is there any way to recover the existing procedures?

Answer (score 0):

A backup of the database may be performed through cPanel, which includes the procedures.